# d3 ticks function does not return same number of time ticks as specified in input/argument. (React JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, charts

I am trying to build a responsive chart in React JS and I am not very familiar with D3. I noticed in my code ticks functions doesn't return same number of ticks as I specified. here is my code:

```
 const pixelsPerTick = 90;

    const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
        .domain([moment(xDomain[0]).toDate(), moment(xDomain[1]).toDate()])
        .range(xRange);

    const getXOffset = value => xScale(moment(value).toDate());
    const getYOffset = value => {
        const elementIndex = yDomain.findIndex(item => item === value);
        return (elementIndex + 1) * 50;
    };
    const numberOfTicksTarget = Math.max(
        1,
        Math.floor(
            (xRange[1] - xRange[0]) / pixelsPerTick
        )
    );

    const xTicks = useMemo(() => {

        return xScale.tickValues(numberOfTicksTarget)
            .map(value => ({
                value,
                xOffset: xScale(moment(value).toDate());
            }));
    }, [
        xDomain.join("-"),
        xRange.join("-")
    ]);
```

In addition even though I wrote **const pixelsPerTick = 90;** the pixel per tick does not seem to be always the same. Also if  **numberOfTicksTarget** is 11, the **xTicks** returns an array of 11 element.